How to sculpt one object with context to another without joining

In this picture i have a kerb that is peeled up, and i want to flatten it and make it so there are no gaps. How can I do this without joining the objects, as it will not work in-game if i join the objects? The problem i run into is flattening does not seem to take the road into account when i sculpt.
Ideas:
-loft the edges somehow (?) Then anchor the new edge of the ground mesh and flatten?
-flatten on y axis only somehow taking road into account?

Do you use dyntopo? Otherwise I don't see why you couldn't join and after sculpting separate

I do not want the road to be adjusted

OK then, make a copy of road, join it with the rest, sculpt the rest, delete the road in the amalgamate?

ah this is smart.

one other thing i found is can manually click on the edge vertices of the ground and snap to edge transalte, but it is just a lot of manual work. my issue with deleting the road in the amalgamate is that it is is not cut and clear what the road is anymore though i can do a projected cut i believe

Why don't you add more topology to the terrain and then put shrinkwrap mod on the it so that it snaps to the road?
